# Amplifying long run wiring to addressable WS2815 LED 12V to pool line noise issues

Tags: led, amplifier, spi, data, line

I amurrently working on running WS2825 IP68 lighting (finishing up) in our pool along with LED lights. After moving the controllers to a centralized location, we have been having issues (lights flickering, unable to have correct program setting or correct color set based on data line) with the long runs now for the data and backup lines coming up with either a suitable amplifier for the 12V data for the 150 foot lines coming from the LED drivers that will control the addressable LEDs. We have tried several of the purchased options but are looking for design recommendations or other options for data amplifier design (tried super lighting led, etc.) but still running into issues. The lines are run with 18 AWG to the pool. 20 AWG to the LED lines.

Also trying to use these 3 pin/4 pin (2 data one primary line one backup) that are suppose to be perfect for install on the LED front end for this - after the 100-150 foot runs of the 18 AWG wiring but having zero luck. Lights are still flickering, incorrect colors, unable to see correct program on controller.

[image]

Trying to understand this amplifier circuit a bit better as this design doesn’t match the schematic on the web page from than manufacturer

https://www.superlightingled.com/dc1224v-mini-spi-amplifier-for-3pin-single-signal-and-4pin-backup-addressable-led-strip-lights-p-3847.html

Comment: I wonder what your knowledge level is - you need an off-the-shelf product, or you're willing to design your own circuit?

Comment: are we supposed to guess what this means? ... `we have been having issues`

Comment: As for level of knowledge - intermediate but rusty, I’m an engineer but my EE had been a few years. Willing to design or build my own. As for issues, don’t have power drop issues, we ran the power injection, calculated all the loads required for power loss over the runs for the multiple lines. The problem we are having is with the different controllers which are now at the run beginnings - when we try to control the addressable LEDs, we have flashing led and not the programmed results nor any of the basic color sets. We have not gotten around to building out our pi or arduino programming yet.

Comment: Want to stay away from a logic level shifter, and focus on single data amp for primary and secondary lines - tried off the shelf like 901E and BTF lighting Addressable data amp for long lines - neither worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LGTZ73 - Hi, Your 2nd (of 3) questions on this topic has effectively superseded this 1st (of 3) questions on the topic. So I have closed this 1st question as a duplicate of the 2nd one - there is no point in people responding to *this* one, now the you have asked two more.